# What is terminal command line that tells me where system has assigned TMPDIR?

Tags: command-line, tmpfs

I want to type a command in an Ubuntu 15.10 terminal,
that will tell me what folder is being used as the "temporary" folder.
Is there one?
Tx for any comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I can imagine to "where system has assigned TMPDIR" is the directory that is used when programs invoke the `mktemp` command.

As explained in the `mktemp` manual page, this is determined by the environment variable `$TMPDIR`, falling back to `/tmp` if the variable is unset

```
-p DIR, --tmpdir[=DIR]
       interpret TEMPLATE relative to DIR; if DIR is not specified, use
       $TMPDIR  if set, else /tmp.  With this option, TEMPLATE must not
       be an absolute  name;  unlike  with  -t,  TEMPLATE  may  contain
       slashes, but mktemp creates only the final component
```

You can check to see if `$TMPDIR` is set on your system using `echo $TMPDIR` - or more directly, you could run the `mktemp` command with `-u` or `--dry-run` to see what directory it would use

```
-u, --dry-run
       do not create anything; merely print a name (unsafe)
```

e.g.

```
$ mktemp -u
/tmp/tmp.sP1jgc38gg
```

which confirms that in this case it is using `/tmp`.

Comment: I tried "echo $TMPDIR", and it returned blank, so I guess TMPDIR is not set.

Comment: I did "mktemp -u", and it showed like yours, /tmp/tmp.K7WLTtKU8Y.

Comment: @OldGrampa so that all sounds normal for Ubuntu

Comment: Thank you Steeldriver, you gave me the info I was seeking.

Answer (score 1):

The temporary folder, can have two meanings in my mind. You can either have the `/tmp` folder on disk for Ubuntu to use or the swap space.

The swap space is a partition on your disk, acting as extra RAM.

The `/tmp` folder is for programs to store data temporarily until the next reboot.